# GCM XMPP same message received multiple times on server

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM CCS server-client architecture. The problem is sometimes I receive a message multiple times, even though the first time I ACK it, like I do with the rest of the messages. What could be the problem ?

Note that the message I receive multiple times has the exact same XMPP stanza every time, nothing changes (ex, even same message_id, so it's like GCM never received my ACK for the first time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this just happens. Why ? No f*cking idea. The explanation would be that the initial ACK sent from the server to the GCM server is not received, thus GCM sends the message again. In conclusion, just take care in the code for duplicate messages to be on the safe side. Quite pathetic, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Pls see..
"If the connection between CCS and the device is poor, GCM may send multiple, duplicate delivery receipts. You can safely ignore such duplicates."

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs

Comment: What has this got anything to do with the question? The issue in the question was happening server side, not client side. I wasn't receiving multiple delivery receipts. I was receiving multiple upstream messages.